# Sharing the page on Linked in shows the wrong Title and Image

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to share a link of the URL https://www.millerwelds.com/about/fabtech in linked in, and it does not correctly show the image and title. Most of the other pages in the site are working very well. https://www.millerwelds.com/about/sema is a similar page that shows the image and title correctly. https://www.millerwelds.com/about/fabtech incorrectly shows the "Sign up for newsletters". The page also has all og tags in place correctly, so not sure what is missing. Any ideas on what is wrong? Appreciate your help, Thanks!